# How do I input text via an HTML form and retrieve data from a JSON file as a response using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to make a little flashcard quiz game and I'm trying to implement a feature where someone can enter text into an input area and after they press enter the word "Correct" or "Incorrect" is flashed on the screen for 1 second before the input area is blank and the next question get loaded.

Here is a visual of what I am doing:

[image]

In particular, this is the HTML code that generates the input text area below:

```
<form id="answers">
    <input type="text" name="inputtext" id="answer" style="width: 100%; height: 30px;" placeholder="Enter your answer..." onkeyup="checkAnswer(this,event);" autofocus><br>
</form>
```

This is the JSON file which is saved as: questionsAndAnswersItalian.json

```
[{"q":"What is the word for 'where' in Italian?","a":"Dove"},
{"q":"What is the word for 'when' in Italian?","a":"Quando"},
{"q":"What is the word for 'why' in Italian?","a":"Perché"}]
```

This is the javascript code that I've written which isn't working:

```
var jsonUrl = "questionsAndAnswersItalian.json";
var qs;
var numCards;
var maxIndex;

function checkAnswer(input, event){
    if(event.keyCode == 13){
        var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value.toLowerCase();
        var questionNumber = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i<jsonUrl.length; i++){
            if(answer == jsonUrl[questionNumber]["a"].toLowerCase()){
                setTimeout(correct_input, 1000);
                input.value = "";
            }else{
                setTimeout(incorrect_input, 1000);
                input.value = "";
            }
            questionNumber++;
        }
    }
}
function correct_input(){
    input.value = "Correct!";
}
function incorrect_input(){
    input.value = "Incorrect!";
}

function init() {
    $.getJSON(jsonUrl, function(jsonObject) {
        qs = jsonObject;
        numCards = qs.length;
        maxIndex = numCards-1;
        displayCard();
    });
}
```

The functions aren't working as I expected them to and I was wondering if someone could tell me where I am going wrong.

If you need more information to understand what I'm doing here please do not hesitate to ask!

Any help or advice would be much appreciated!

Thank you.

Comment: what it is that is not working as expected?

Comment: After you input an answer, the input area should flash either "Correct!" or "Incorrect!" for 1 second depending on what the person inputted, but from what I've currently written no text is flashed

Comment: First, it looks to me like you're expecting your questions and answers to be magically loaded by setting some variable called jsonURL. You'll need to load them in asynchronously using something like jQuery.ajax.

Comment: also correct_input and incorrect_input are not defined when you're adding them to the set timeout. remember js executes in order

Comment: I just added the code that I forgot to post to the bottom of the code snippet.  How come correct_input and incorrect_input are not defined in the way I've added them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part :

```
    for(var i = 0; i<jsonUrl.length; i++){
        if(answer == jsonUrl[questionNumber]["a"].toLowerCase()){
            setTimeout(correct_input, 1000);
            input.value = "";
        }else{
            setTimeout(incorrect_input, 1000);
            input.value = "";
        }
        questionNumber++;
    }
```

You are looping through a String (jsonUrl), not your jsonObject. Use `qs` instead.

**EDIT:**

Here's a jquery code that works :

```
$('#answer').keyup(function(event) {
    var code = event.keyCode || event.which;

    if (code == 13) {
        var answer = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        var goodAnswer = qs[currentCard].a.toLowerCase();

        if (answer == goodAnswer) {
            setTimeout(correct_input, 1000);
        }
        else {
            setTimeout(incorrect_input, 1000);
        }

        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

Declare `var currentCard = null;` as global and set its value in `displayCard()` where I suppose you do a random or something like that.

With this code you have to remove `onkeyup="checkAnswer(this,event);"`.

**jsfiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/u7bkH/

Comment: I've already experimented by doing this: if(answer == qs[questionNumber]["a"].toLowerCase()) but it only flashes "Incorrect!" and doesn't flash "Correct!" when the right answer is inputted into the input area.  Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Just edited my post. It's not flashing correctly because it sets timeout for each question. So each answer you give, it fires 3 times.

Comment: Look at the jsfiddle I posted in my edit. I did not use the getJSON but it's the same with or without.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer it really helped!  I was wondering if you could briefly explain why my original code with plain javascript  didn't work, and I was wondering what a possible solution could be without having to use jquery. Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. First, you were using the `jsonUrl` (which is a string) in your loop instead of `rs` (json object) - your code should have thrown an error on `jsonUrl[questionNumber]["a"].toLowerCase()`. Second, you were looping on your question array and calling setTimeout at each question. It's so fast you can't see the good answer flashing. The only case that should have worked is the last question.

Comment: By the way, I posted jquery code because of the tag on your question. It's also possible using plain javascript.

Answer (score 0):

the `setTimeout` function requires an asynchronous callback.

**EDIT** a more complete example, but ***note*** that it's only showing the way to correctly use `setTimeout` per your requirements. You'll need to complete with the appropiate check of correctness of the answer.

So, change your code to this

```
$('#answer').keyup(function(event) {
  var code = event.keyCode || event.which;
  if (code == 13) {
    var input = $(this);
    var answer = input.val().toLowerCase();
    if (answer == "correct") {
      input.val("Correct!");
    }
    else {
      input.val("Incorrect!");
    }
    setTimeout(
      function(){
        input.val("");
      },1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: Your suggested change isn't working.  Neither "Correct!" or "Incorrect" is flashed after something is inputted into the input area